# how to limit users to only one comment and rating per Item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements

This is what I have in the back-end controller: 
'use strict';

```
 var   Comment = require('../../../models/comment');

module.exports = {
    description: 'Create a Comment',
    notes: 'Create a comment',
    tags:['comment'],

    handler: function(request, reply){
        console.log('COMMM PAY', request.payload);
        Comment.create({
            itemId: request.payload.itemId,
            text: request.payload.commentText,
            rating: request.payload.rating,
            userId: request.auth.credentials._id
        }, function(err, comment){
            reply(comment);
        });
    }
};
```

This is what I have in the front-end controller:

```
$scope.createComment = function(comment, item, rating){
                            var body = {itemId:item.itemId,
                                commentText: comment.text,
                                rating: rating};

                        Comment.create(body).then(function(res){
                            toastr.success('Review Submitted.');
                            console.log('RESdfdas.data',res.data);
                            $scope.comments.push(res.data);
                            $scope.showCommentForm = !!!$scope.showCommentForm;
                            $scope.comment = {};
                            getComments();
                        });
                        };
```

How do I make it so users can only give one comment / rating per item? I know I need an if/else conditional that states if there is already a matching document / comment object that has a matching userId && itemId then to return an error?

Not sure if you need to see my html / jade.

Comment: It sounds like you just answered your own question

Comment: how do I check if those already exist within the collection though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose/mongo makes this super easy to do. All you would need to do is something like this in your server side route for creating comments.

```
Comment.findOne({userId : request.auth.credentials._id}, function(err,data) {
  if (err) {
    // If err (doesn't find a comment made by that user)
    // Then create one
  } else {
    // If it hits here, it means there was already a comment from that user
    // So kick them out or whatever
  }
}
```

There's a few ways to do this, use this as something to guide your thinking.

Comment: yeah. I made that harder than it had to be. so if it exist, kick out, if not create comment. simple. thx.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could approach this. If using a db, I would have an 'events' table (collection) that every time somebody rates it logs an identifier to them and the content they rated. Then you can disable the rating/commenting if they already have a matching record.

A less absolute way would be to store something in localstorage and then check... but that information could get erased giving them access to rate/comment again.

Comment: I'm using mongodb / mongoose for the db. From what you've stated and I was thinking before, I need to put the check on the server side. What is the check I need to do to see what if what i'm getting back from the payload already exists. Specifically if there is already a document / object in the collection has the same UserId and ItemId properties?